what we need to know the risk of using Android Custom Tab
We are considering using the Android Custom tab for our mobile application. We have almost completed development and are now doing our test. During our testing, one of our team members was concerned about whether using the Android Custom tab would be risky for us or the end user.
Because, as I saw it, when we did an action to open a webview in a Mobile app, in case using custom tab, it would launch webpage separately from the mobile app, like a browser. So one of our team members is concerned that the user session might leak.
I just read this article. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/122.0.6253.7/docs/security/custom-tabs-faq.md But my concern has not been clear yet, so I am asking here.
I hope someone with knowledge about this answers my question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
